# Why does my function only take the first element of a column instead of the whole column

Tags: r, shiny

So what I want to do is take the column "conc" from chlorideframe, divide it by the value cc0valueschloride, and then stick it back into a new dataframe cc0chloride.
I have some reactive value, cc0chloride which I want to be a dynamic dataframe.

```
cc0chloride<-reactiveValues(conc=0)
```

I want to divide a column in the dataframe called "conc" with this value I define here cc0valueschloride

```
cc0valueschloride<-reactive({cindat()[1,2]})

observeEvent(input$run_button, {
    req(chlorideframe())
    cc0chloride$conc<-chlorideframe()$conc/cc0valueschloride()
  })
```

But this only returns the one value in the column, instead of 200. I'm not sure why this doesn't divide the entire column conc and store it into a new list.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: `[1,2]` means always the first row of second column. If you want to do whole column, `[, 2]`